# Generate forms from serializer

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, material-ui

I'm working with React in the front-end with Material-UI, and I would like to auto generate forms based on my serializer's schema.

Usually, the way that CRUD works in the app is by listing the registers, and then give the option to add, edit, or remove registers.
So, my idea would be to get the serializer's schema in the listing part of the CRUD and then use it to generate the forms later on. Is there anyway to do this? I'm thinking about maybe creating an npm package to help on it...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ModelSerializer` and `ModelViewSet`, you can get the description of the serializer schema sending an `OPTIONS` request to the endpoint and use it in the front end for building your form based on that information. You even get the choices when the field of the model has them set.

Comment: I'm currently using viewsets.ViewSet. Couldn't find any alternative [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset). Is there anyway to do it with that? Thanks

Comment: use `viewsets.ModelViewSet`instead

Comment: You can check it here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset